# using parent controller in included html files

Tags: angularjs

I am developing one angularjs app.
I have two files.
1) index.html 2)signup.html
I have included signup.html in index.html using ng-include. I have one Submit button on signup.html.

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="temp1()">
```

when user clicks on submit I want to show him alert box for now. what i did I used parent ng-app and ng-controller in signup.html like this

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('AppController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.temp1()  = function()
    {
        alert('clicked');  
    };
});
```

but its not working
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: I have answered your question. Can you check if it's fine for u and mark it as solved ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is because your object is primitive. You should take a look this to [learn more about $scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

so you should make your variable a complex object so you can use them on child controllers.

```
$scope.functions  = {
   temp1: function(){
      alert('clicked');  
   }
}
```

and in your html call it like this

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="functions.temp1()">
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `()` from temp1

```
$scope.temp1  = function()
{
  alert('clicked');  

};
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's wrong way to declare functions**

```
$scope.temp1()  = function()
```

Angularjs follows functions to be assigned inside a object **$scope** or **$rootScope** so that it can be watch later in $digest loop

It is as simple as adding attribute in a object .In javascript object can contain any kind of values whether a string or any **function**

```
$scope.temp1=function(){

}
```

is just as simple as that we are giving an attribute of function type so that it can be called later on like this

Inside controller

```
$scope.temp1()
```

Inside HTML

```
<div ng-click='temp1()'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

**html file**

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="submit" ng-click="temp1()">
</div>
```

**js file**

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.temp1 = function() {
      alert('clicked');
    };
  });
```

You can take a look into this codepen, it's working : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwwPmM

Comment: Thanks friend but its not working as per requirement